# Testing Laravel 5.3 protected API

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I have just set up a small Laravel API that is protected via Passport that was introduced in 5.3. So far, everything is working well.

Since I will be the only one consuming the API, I simply added `\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class` to my web middleware-group in order to generate and handle my API tokens.

To my question: How may I handle tokens in my application tests? `actingAs($user)` does not seem to magically add the user's token to the request. I can use `$this->withoutMiddleware();`, but then all middleware is disabled, and not only the one responsible for authentication.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thank you very much for you help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A much easier solution is to add the `api` guard to the `actingAs()` method:

```
$this->actingAs($user, 'api');
```

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing and is the correct answer. It's right in the docs also. Unsure, why I didn't see that when I asked this question about one year ago :)

Answer (score 3):

I finally made it work by building upon on this answer:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/passport-personal-access-token-unit-test

Copy pasted from the author of above-mentioned post:

```
/**
 *@test
 */
public function Create_an_access_token()
{

    $clientRepository = new ClientRepository();
    $client = $clientRepository->createPersonalAccessClient(
        null, 'Test Personal Access Client', 'http://localhost'
    );

    DB::table('oauth_personal_access_clients')->insert([
        'client_id' => $client->id,
        'created_at' => new DateTime,
        'updated_at' => new DateTime,
    ]);

    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    $token = $user->createToken('TestToken')->accessToken;

    $header = [];
    $header['Accept'] = 'application/json';
    $header['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '.$token;

    $this->json('GET', '/api/user', [], $header)
             ->seeJson([
             'id' => $user->id,
             'email' => $user->email,
             'name' => $user->name,
    ]);
}
```

I extracted the relevant and reusable parts into a small helper-class, and now the testing-code is rather short and readable.

Hope this helps someone in a similar situation.

Comment: You can also call ```$this->artisan('passport:install');``` during setup

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the existing Laravel Passport tests, this should provide you sufficient information on how to clearly test this:

https://github.com/laravel/passport/tree/master/tests

Comment: Thanks Ryan!
The Passport tests definitely helped for my understanding, but I still haven't been able to make a successful test call.

Let's say my test looks like this:
`$user = factory(\App\User::class)->create();
  $this->actingAs($user)->json('GET', '/api/products/')`
How can I make this pass the auth-middleware on `/api/products`?
Thanks again for your help!